# d3.js - show hierarchy in pie by csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I'm new to d3.js but I have made some practices already.
I have a pie chart which is devided into 19 pieces (picture1)based on this csv file (picture2). Each piece means a year and the area of that piece means its score.  [Picture 1&2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg4ms.jpg)

Now I want to build a parent-children relationship in the csv, like picture 3(each year will contains 5 continents). [Picture3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZr6c.png) The sum of five continents' scores equals to the score of that year.

And I want the pie to be change so that all pieces are cut into 5 layers from inner side to out side.

Part of my current code is here. Can anyone tell me how to make the hierarchy? If the structure in picture3 is not right, how should the structure be?

And do I need json? if so, how to change the data loading part for csv files into for json files?

```
    var width = 650, height = 650, radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2, innerRadius=0;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function(d) { return d.width; });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius)
      .outerRadius(function (d) {
        return (radius - innerRadius) * Math.sqrt(d.data.score / 2900.0) + innerRadius;
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

//data loading
    d3.csv('./src/InCountry-v1.csv', function(error, data) {

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.id     =  d.year;
        d.order  = +d.order;
        d.color  =  d.color;
        d.weight = +d.weight;
        d.score  = +d.score;
        d.width  = +d.weight;
        d.label  =  d.label;
      });

    var path = svg.selectAll(".solidArc")
           .data(pie(data))
           .enter().append("path")
           .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color})
           .attr("class", "solidArc")
           .attr("stroke", "gray")
           .attr("d", arc)
           .attr("opacity",0.5)
           .on("mouseenter", function() {d3.select(this)
                                           .style("fill", function(d) { return d.data.color})
                                           .attr("opacity",1); })
           .on("mouseleave", function() { d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.5); });
```

Comment: Dear Tina, did my answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to preprocess your data to give it the structure you need.

For this you can define a `dataPreparation` function:

```
function dataPreparation ( data ) {
  var byYear = {};
  var result = [];

  data.forEach(function (d) {
    if ( !byYear.hasOwnProperty(d.year) ) {
      byYear[d.year] = {
        year: d.year, 
        order: +d.order, 
        score: +d.score, 
        weight: +d.weight,
        width: +d.width,
        color: d.color,
        label: d.label,
        entries: [d]
      };
      result.push(byYear[d.year]);
    } else {
      byYear[d.year].score += +d.score;
      byYear[d.year].entries.push(d);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

And then in your csv load callback, you can do:

```
d3.csv('./src/InCountry-v1.csv', function(error, data) {
  var hierarchicalData = dataPreparation(data);
```

And the provide your `hierarchicalData` to your `pie` generator function.

Good luck!